# How can I download a text file in Flask using make_response?

Tags: python, rest, flask

I would like to down a text file in my directory to use make_response in Flask, but a code that I wrote down does not work out.

Here is a code that I wrote down to download a text file using make_response.

```
@api.route('/structure_voice_log', methods=['POST'])
def download():
    response = make_response("hogehoge")
    response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=outbound.txt"
    response.headers["Content-type"] = "text/plain"
    return response
```

Here is the command that I issued.

```
curl -L -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:17354/structure_voice_log -X POST -d '{"voice_log": "hogehoge"}'
```

Here is the outcome after the above command has ended.

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-type: text/plain
Content-Length: 8
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=outbound.txt
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Server: Werkzeug/0.15.5 Python/3.7.5
Date: Tue, 12 Nov 2019 16:15:44 GMT

hogehoge%
```

What I got is just a string "hogehoge" rather than a text file.
How can I make it?
I might go wrong using this framework.
I will really appreciate it if you help me out.

Answer (score 1):

the `make_response` take in first arguments a string to display.
May be use the `send_file` function instead (https://pythonise.com/series/learning-flask/sending-files-with-flask).

Hope it helps.
best regards